# How to add custom attributes to a specific category in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes

I need to add some custom attributes to a category in Magento. I only want to use for a special category, not all.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that you want products in category A have a set of attributes while products in category B have another set of attributes?
If so, you should create a new attribute set in Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute Sets, and add all attributes you need for the specific category. And when you create products for this category, just choose the new attribute set.
Well if it is not what you mean, please give more detailed explanation.
Hope it helps

Comment: Please use comments to clarify OP's question, then answer once clarity has been provided.

Comment: You have understood my intentions but I want it as in the picture https://prnt.sc/gihqx9